# how to sorting array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array `arr = [a_1, a_5, a_0, a_4, a_2, a_4];`

I need re sorting array above:

output: `arr2 = [a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5];`

thanks!

Comment: By following the directions in any one of the 6,900,000 google results for "how to sorting array in javascript".

Comment: Too difficult to find this: [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = ['a_1', 'a_5', 'a_0', 'a_4', 'a_2', 'a_4'];
arr.sort(function(x, y){ return x.split('_')[1] > y.split('_')[1]});
alert(arr);
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUF3e/)